# Mocking an Excel workbook

Tags: c#

I have some unit tests that require reading an excel file which is painfully slow, so I was wondering if I could mock an excel workbook object using Moq. Has anybody got any experience with this? If so how would I go about this?

Comment: You might be able to mole it: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/. Found this related post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/pex/thread/02d1b794-1bb6-4a5b-b66b-85a34d0abbe7.

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't the appropriate thing to do not be to wrap excel in some kind of interface only providing the connectivity that you actually use, and then have both a real implementation connectiong to excel as well as a mocking implementation for tests?

Comment: +1. Keep it simple. An interface defining the things you need to do with Excel. A class implementing that interface that talks to Excel, used by your application. A class implementing that interface that pretends to talk to Excel, used by your unit tests. This of course assumes you don't care about how the Excel file interacts with your application!

Comment: Depending on the extent of "the things you need to do with Excel", that may look like re-writting Excel by yourself.. And I am not even talking about how likely you are to make mistakes in the behaviour of your mocked Excel. Having said that,  I would love to be proven wrong!

Comment: Mocking the functionality of excel would be hubris and endless work. But the question was only about reading an excel file at specific conditions. Thus the suggestion is to wrap the »ReadFile« method in an interface and test that the file is read when it is supposed to.

Answer (score 2):

Another thought. If you're happy to mock the object and keep it all in memory, you could consider reading the excel file once, in the unit test fixture setup, and then keeping that object in memory for the duration of your test session.